# jmeter and random number distribution

Tags: jmeter

I would like to use jmeter, but I need to get it to generate random numbers using a gaussian distribution. Any idea on how to achieve that? All I can see is a Minimum Value and a Maximum Value for the random variable `config element`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSR223 Pre or Post processor depend on your requirement to generate random using Gaussian distribution.
Below is the code:-

```
rnd = new Random()
result = (1..1000).inject([]) { r, i -> r << rnd.nextGaussian() }

log.info ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+result
```

Below is the reference from where I have got this.
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Random_numbers#Groovy

One more reference, for Java and many others:-
http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/ECC/gauss.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that:)

Comment: This advice was an excellent pointer for me. JSR223 scripts are super powerful